# Can I disable the SSH server on my Actiontec Q1000?

Tags: ssh, router, modem, dsl

I have DSL service through CenturyLink and my DSL modem/router has SSH enabled. I do not use the command line to configure the router and I want to access a Linux machine sitting behind the router via SSH. I setup port forwarding, but when I try to SSH to the Linux box the SSH server on the router responds instead.

Does anyone know how I can permanently disable the SSH server on the router? So far I haven't been able to find a configuration option in the web GUI...

Answer (score 2):

From the router's web-based administration, you can edit the URL to access the hidden menus. Try `main.html` and `tr69.html`.

Comment: Thanks David, both the URLs you suggested were available. However, I still didn't see any options to disable the SSH server on the router itself... :-(